# Android Studio doesn't ask me about target device

Tags: android, android-studio

In my run configuration for an app I've got "use same device for future launches" **unchecked**, though it runs always on the same target, until I kill the process myself, or the build fails. It doesn't matter if I start new emulator instances on the way.

Is this a bug in AS? Can I come around it a little cleaner than killing the process?

(Android Studio 2.3, 64-bit Linux)

Comment: how many devices do you have ?

Comment: one emulator running and one physical phone connected. I'll try how it behaves with more devices

Comment: and it runs in phone ?

Comment: doesn't matter actually. If I start a new emulator, it behaves the same

Comment: dont know why people do that...

Comment: ok, it turned out it's caused by _instant run_ turned on - when turned off, it behaves as expected - which is perfectly fine. Should I remove the question or answer it myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please make sure you **Stop** the app first and then **Run** it again, then a prompt will appear asking for the target device.

I use macOS Sierra, I go through the following path to change settings if I face the problem you mentioned.

Run > Edit Configurations > app > Deployment Target Options.

Comment: this seems to be the way to go. **Stop** is easily reached by `ctrl+f2`, by the way

Comment: well, it seems to be specific for a system... I just checked on a windows machine, where it works as intended - i.e., when I leave "use for future launches" unchecked, it just asks me every time to restart the app and choose from devices. I am afraid I need to state it as the correct answer, and remove "accepted" mark from yours. And it seems I need to dig deeper into AS bugtracker as well.

Comment: I have mentioned the method by which you can change the device(if you check 'for future launches' checkbox) I thought that was the case with you

Comment: ok, your answer answers my question (there is no cleaner way for linux/macos), even when you were mistaken, so it's best when I leave it as it is :)

You can perhaps add that it is now unfortunately platform dependent, so that people can find that information faster.

Answer (score 4):

Since Android Studio 3.5 you can choose deployment target from the drop-down menu in the toolbar. Big plus: you can run on multiple devices in a one-shot.

[image: device connection button in Android Studio toolbar]